# Form Input value property not behaving as expected

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to create a form to collect input to create an event listing.
I am using the 'value' property in way it is documented in the React docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

,to collect user input onChange, but material-ui:

https://material-ui.com/api/input/

uses 'value' for setting value to the input field not collecting the value in the field. This is causing all sort of bugs, e.i. not being able to enter input, pickers not displaying default values and not accepting values and also not being able to collect information. I could use pointers on where I am going wrong. Thanks for having a look :-)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    }
});

class CreateEvent extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: "",
            description: "",
            location: "",
            start_time: "",
            start_date: "",
            end_time: "",
            end_date: ""
        };
    }

    updateInput = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    cancelCreation = e =>{

    };

    addNewEvent = e =>{
        //Make db call
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="form-container">
                <Paper className="new-event-form">
                    <form className="event-form" onSubmit={this.addNewEvent}>
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Event title"
                            className="event-title"
                            inputProps={{
                                'aria-label': 'Description',
                            }}
                            multiline={1}
                            rows={1}
                            onChange={this.updateInput}
                            value={this.state.value}

                        />
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Event description"
                            className="event-title"
                            inputProps={{
                                'aria-label': 'Description',
                            }}
                            multiline={true}
                            rows={10}
                            onChange={this.updateInput}
                            //value={this.state.description}

/*
Will allow user to provide input because 'value' is commented out. But the above component will not because value is referenced
*/
                        />
                        <Grid container spacing={16} className="event-grid">
                            <Grid  item xs={4}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    item xs={4}
                                    placeholder="Event location"
                                    className="event-location"
                                    inputProps={{
                                        'aria-label': 'Description',
                                    }}
                                    multiline={true}
                                    rows={4}
                                    onChange={this.updateInput}
                                    //value={this.state.location}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={4}>
                                <TextField
                                    id="date"
                                    label="Start date"
                                    type="date"
                                    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                                    className="event-start-date"
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                        shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                    onChange={this.updateInput}
                                    value={this.state.start_date}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    id="time"
                                    label="Start time"
                                    type="time"
                                    defaultValue="07:30"
                                    className="event-start-time"
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                        shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                    inputProps={{
                                        step: 300, // 5 min
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={4}>
                                <TextField
                                    id="date"
                                    label="End date"
                                    type="date"
                                    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                                    className="event-start-date"
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                        shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    id="time"
                                    label="End time"
                                    type="time"
                                    defaultValue="07:30"
                                    className="event-start-time"
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                        shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                    inputProps={{
                                        step: 300, // 5 min
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button className="line-spacer"/>
                        <Grid container className="form-buttons">
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Input type="file" name="my-event-image" id="file" className="new-event-image"> </Input>
                                <label htmlFor="file">CHOOSE AN IMAGE</label>
                                <Button className="line-spacer"  onChange={this.updateInput}/>

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid container spacing={16} className="form-buttons">
                            <Grid  item xs={6}>
                                <Button onChange={this.cancelCreation}>Cancel</Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={6}>
                                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CreateEvent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `updateInput` method you use `e.target.name` but none of your input fields have a `name` property. Add a `name` property on each `Input` component matching the name you are using in your value. For example:

```
<Input name="description" ... value={this.state.description} .../>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, added 'name'. It works like a charm.